# How to copy data from one table to another with different columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL Server table (let's call it `Table 1`) with the following columns:

1. ID
2. Wager
3. TransactionType

I am trying to copy all the data from the above table to a temp table.

The problem is that the temp table has different column names:

1. ID
2. Stake
3. TransactionTypeID
4. Markets (Not Null)
5. Odds (Not Null)

I am getting all of the data from Table 1 via a stored procedure and inserting it into the temp table as described in the code below:

```
INSERT @TempTable0
EXEC [server].[DB].[dbo].[stored_proc] @ClientID = @ClientID,
    @StartDate = @StartDate,
    @EndDate = @EndDate;
```

I would like to know how I can achieve the following:

1. Insert data from the `Wager` column from `Table 1` into the `Stake` of the temp table.
2. Insert data from the `TransactionType` column from `Table 1` into the `TransactionTypeID` of the temp table.
3. Assign default values to `Odds` and `Markets`.

Comment: I don't think you can directly do this. Either define a middleman table and insert the values from the proc into that table and then form an insert query for your temp table or you can define only the necessary columns in your temp table, do the insert and then alter the table and add the remaining columns.

Comment: You can specify the column names when inserting via stored procedure. And you can create your temp table with default values

Comment: Does that `[server].[DB].[dbo].[stored_proc]` returns all the required column from `Table 1`?

Comment: If we take the proc out of the equation here and assume that it populates Table1, then you can just use standard `insert` syntax to do thi https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#OtherTables `insert into temp (Stake, TransactionTypeId,  Odds, Markets) SELECT Wager, TransactionType, 'DefaultValue','DefaultValue' from [Table 1]`

Comment: @Squirrel no, not all of the columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this fiddle. It's for Postgresql, but you can use same approach in SQL Server too. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vMwUWprVeFQQ5wpzoaG9Ho/0

Basic concept that you need to use `insert into select` statement.

```
insert
into
    tempTable
    select
        ID,
        Wager as Stake,
        TransactionType as TransactionTypeID,
        'markets' as Markets,
        'odds' as Odds
    from table1;
```